# Is Google-Anthos AMP for hybrid-cloud supported in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, hybrid-cloud, google-anthos

I hear Google's Anthos is supporting hybrid cloud, and has features for building applications that are cloud-agnostic.

Does Amazon-AWS support integration with Anthos AMP?

From enterprise standpoint, I prefer not to be locked with AWS, so would be great if AWS integrates with Anthos AMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that Google Anthos was just announced this month at Google Next '19, details will change over time.

I do not expect that AWS will directly support Google Anthos.

Google has stated that Google will provide a single managed service that supports Google Anthos. I translate the statements by Urs Hölzle (Google Sr VP) as: Google Anthos support will be provided as part of your Google Support agreement no matter where Google Anthos is running - GCP, Azure, AWS, or On-premises.

Comment: What is equivalent of GCP Anthos in AWS and Azure ? How Anthos works ?

Comment: @ArvindKumar - You should create a new question. Neither AWS nor Azure has its own equivalent to Anthos. AWS has partnered with Red Hat OpenShift. Azure has partnered with Rancher. All three are promising products/services. I did a podcast last month that included OpenShift, etc. https://ibm.jhanley.com/ibm/getting-started-with-ibm-cloud-red-hat-openshift-serverless-containers/

Comment: Thanks John. I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778629/multi-cloud-solution-for-data-platforms-on-hybrid-and-multi-cloud-using-anthos